# Python extract part of file name regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and trying to analyse some data. So I've imported and concatenated all the csv files in a folder into a single dataframe. I'm trying to extract part of the file name to use as a header and after searching, I find that you'd normally use regex.

The filenames are like this: `'Varying Concentration2_20190712-145158_Base Media.csv'`, `'Varying Concentration2_20190712-145158_250 g per l.csv'`, etc
So the part I'm trying to extract is after the `_` and before the `.csv`.

I've tried:

```py
for fname in all_data:
    res = re.findall("(?<=_)(\w+).csv$", fname)
    if not res: continue
    print (res)
```

and also `"(?<=[0-9]+_)(\w+)"`
but it does not seem to work.

The desired output would be a list containing `'Base Media'`, `'150g per l`' and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option which avoid regex and instead uses the base `split` string function, twice:

```
filename = 'Varying Concentration2_20190712-145158_Base Media.csv'
parts = filename.split('_')
nameonly = parts[len(parts)-1].split('.')[0]
print(nameonly)
```

Output:

```
Base Media
```

If the full filename could also contains dots, then this answer might need to be adjusted.

Comment: or just ```extract = (filename.split('_')[-1]).split('.')[0]```

Comment: `header = filename.rsplit('_', 1)[-1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]`.

Comment: When I saw your better versions I was just like `:-O`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.csv$)
```

- `(?<=_)` is zero-width positive lookbehind that matches `_`
- `[^_]+` matches one or more characters that are not `_`, this is our desired portion
- `(?=\.csv$)` is zero-width positive lookahead makes sure we have `csv` at the end after the match

If you don't want to use lookarounds, you can use plain patterns and put the desired match in first (and only) captured group (and get the output by `match.group(1)` instead of `match.group()`):

```
_([^_]+)\.csv$
```

**Example:**

```
In [38]: text = 'Varying Concentration2_20190712-145158_Base Media.csv'

In [39]: re.search(r'(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.csv$)', text).group()
Out[39]: 'Base Media'

In [40]: text = 'Varying Concentration2_20190712-145158_250 g per l.csv'

In [41]: re.search(r'(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.csv$)', text).group()
Out[41]: '250 g per l'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

`^.*_(.*)\.csv$`

All this does is skips everything until `_` then captures everything until `.csv`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUfzDK/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
_([^._]+).csv
```

and take the first captured group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TfKXux/1/)

Explanation:

`_([^._]+)` you find `_` and to ensure it's the last on in the string, you exculde `_` from the repetition `[^_]`. You also exculude a dot, to avoid matching the extension `.csv` and that's why you repeat `[^._]+`. It's wrapped in brackets `([^._]+)` making it a capturing group that you can use later.

In python:

```
>>> text = 'Varying Concentration2_20190712-145158_Base Media.csv'
>>> re.search(r'_([^._]+).csv', text).group(1)
'Base Media'
```